# check if the file is audio file in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm writing code to upload audio file (could be in any format .mp3, mp4, .wav and many more...)
I dont want to write all the conditions for all the mime types and then check uploaded file to validate the mime type. Because, I want to ACCEPT ALL the audio files(not just one or two formats).

So, is there any simple way to check whether the file is audio or not?

Thank you!

Comment: you can check file extension while uploading file ..

Comment: there are lots of file formats..
check this site. http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/audio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the audio files format has `"audio/"` common in MIME Type. So, we can check the `$_FILES['file']['mime_type']` and apply a `preg_match()` to check if `"audio/"` exists in this mime type or not.

```
if(preg_match('/audio/i', $_FILES['file']['mime_type']))
    echo 'It is an Audio File';
```

OR

```
if(explode("/", $_FILES['file']['mime_type'])[0] == "audio")
    echo 'It is an Audio File';
```

Comment: `explode("/", $_FILES['file']['mime_type'])[0] === "audio"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple function

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('mime_content_type')) {

    function mime_content_type($filename) {

        $mime_types = array(

            // audio/video
            'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',

        );

        $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename)));
        if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)) {
            return "THIS IS AUDIO FILES";
        }
        else {
            return 'application/octet-stream';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont want to write the list of thousands of mime types

Answer (score 0):

You must know all mime type's of audio and video, this is the list of audio & video mimes

```
<?php
$audio_mime_types = array(
    'audio/mpeg'
);
?>
```

and then check your file by using this

```
$path = $_FILES['your_files_input']['name'];
$ext = mime_content_type($path);

if(!empty($audio_mime_types[$ext])){
   return "This is audio video file";
}
```

Comment: its a huge list...
here you can see more formats
http://www.fileinfo.com/filetypes/audio

Comment: moreover, I dont want video formats... I want to have audio formats

Comment: don't check files by file name extension, its very insecure. Check the **Mime-Type** with Fileinfo http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.fileinfo.php or mime_content_type (**Deprecated**)

Comment: @AdrianPreuß Agree!! I think, all the audio formats has "audio/" common. So, I think, we can check that and apply a preg_match()...
isn't it? is it secure?

Comment: Yeah, he had changed it. Before he had used **mime_content_type**, he had checked **only** the file extension like video **.mp4** - Potential insecure, you can inject code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose common audio extensions or all extensions into an array one time. Then validate through that array you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can see with "console.log(document.getElementById("your_file").files[0])" one of the data from console is "type: audio/mpeg". So you can validations with type of ur file like this:

```
$format_audio = $_FILES['your_file']['type'];
if ($format_audio != "audio/mpeg") {
   // your command
}
```